# strip_tags truncating JSON

Tags: php, json, string, strip-tags, truncated

I have a JSON Response like this:

```
 {
  "id":"2461",
  "name":"GEORGIA INSTITUTE OF <leo_highlight style=border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 150); background-c",
  "logo":"",
  "address":null,
  "city":null,
  "state":null,
  "campus_uri":"{{PATH}}2461\/"
 },
 ....
 ....
```

When I do `strip_tgs` on this one, the whole JSON string is getting truncated at the `name` tag above. The JSON string looks like this.

```
{"id":"2461","name":"GEORGIA INSTITUTE OF
```

All below this line is gone. This is a huge JSON. But its getting truncated here.
Any ideas on what to do? I need to strip out all HTML tags.

**Update:**
Adding more details...

This JSON string I got is from encoding the query results array. So I get array from MySQL query and I encoded it with `json_encode` and trying to `strip_tags` on it.

Comment: The problem is that the name has `<` with no matching `>`. So it looks like the tag never ends.

Comment: Yes, I see that issue. But it shouldn't be stripping out the whole string after that line?

Comment: OK so if you control the JSON creation, why not strip the tags before your serialize it?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? Tags are allowed to span multiple lines. `strip_tags` doesn't know this is JSON, this function is intended to be used on HTML data.

Comment: @Barmar. I agree that point. The string is different here. If there is no end tag, then I guess it shouldn't treat that as a HTML tag or leave it unstripped.

Comment: Garbage In, Garbage Out. Don't use `strip_tags` if it's not HTML.

Comment: Thats what I expect from `strip_tags`. But thats not happening here. Of course, there are valid tags too, which should be stripped out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$val) { $val = strip_tags($val); });
$json = json_encode($json);
```

As simple... Decode it, walk through and encode it.

Comment: @KevinRave then execute my array_walk_recursive call before encoding and everything's sane - instead of using strip_tags after encoding

Comment: How does this work? Are you encoding each element of each JSON object separately? Sorry, trying to understand what it does.

Comment: @KevinRave array_walk_recursive is something of a deep foreach using a callback. It changes every single non-array entry of the whole array by reference. See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: Does it work for the format `Array (  [123] => Array ( [123] => asdfasd))`?

Comment: @KevinRave It should work for every array. (also for multidimensional arrays)

Comment: Basically an Array of Arrays

Comment: @KevinRave Yes. It's recursive through the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Strip out the tags after you have decoded the JSON object. You might do this in a lazy fashion (i.e. when needed) rather than go through every item an strip tags on all fields.